# Display two modal view controllers one after another with different transition styles between them

Tags: iphone, ios, modalviewcontroller, uimodaltransitionstyle

I'm presenting a modalViewController with UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical and then, when the user selects a row of this modalView, I present another modalView as follows:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CenterViewController *nextView = [[CenterViewController alloc] init];

    nextView.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:nextView animated:YES];
    [nextView release];
}
```

The problem is that the transition style remains UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical no matter what type of transition style mode I initialize for this second modal view controller.

Am I missing something relevant?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIModelPresentaionStyle` is used to tell iOS you want it FullScreen or PageSheet..etc. , in your case you should use UIModelTransitionStyle .. so if you did like this it should work.

```
nextView.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd try removing the old one first, and then presenting the new one.

Doesn't sound like a great technique though. Why not have you first modal view controller be some sort of container controller, and present the new view with a flip.